# JSON array data is not getting deleted properly from the localStorage

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am currently displaying the JSON array from localStorage to a table using jquery.
The fields in the JSON array are :

```
name,emailId,phoneNo,category
```

Now in the table I am showing a checkbox also with name as the category and value as the phoneNo.
Now when I select the checkboxes and click on delete , the code for it is as follows:

```
$('#DeleteButton').click(function(){

        $('input:checkbox[name='+categorySelected+']').each(function() 
                {    
                    if($(this).is(':checked'))
                        {
                        var valueOfCheckbox=$(this).val();


                        var getUserDetails=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userDetails"));

                        for(i=0;i<getUserDetails.length;i++)
                            {
                            if(getUserDetails[i].phoneNo==valueOfCheckbox)
                                {
                                getUserDetails[i].category="";
                                }
                            }


                        }
                    localStorage.setItem("userDetails", JSON.stringify(getUserDetails));
                    $('#insertData').append(displayItems);

                });

    });
```

I am displaying the data as per the category , so if there is no category so that data will not be displayed, so in the above code I am setting the category of the particular record to "". After running the above code the data inside the localStorage becomes undefined.

My HTML data is:

```
<table id="insertData"  cellspacing="3">
</table>
```

And I am creating the table like this:

```
var displayItems="";

    var getItemsFromStorage=localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
    var getCategory=localStorage.getItem("category");

    if(getItemsFromStorage!=null)
        {

        var getItemsFromStorageJSON=JSON.parse(getItemsFromStorage);

        var i;
        for( i=0;i<getItemsFromStorageJSON.length;i++)
            {
            if((getItemsFromStorageJSON[i].category)==getCategory)
                {

                displayItems+="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='"+getItemsFromStorageJSON[i].category+"' value='"+getItemsFromStorageJSON[i].phoneNo+"'/></td><td>"+getItemsFromStorageJSON[i].name+"</td><td>"+getItemsFromStorageJSON[i].emailId+"</td><td>"+getItemsFromStorageJSON[i].phoneNo+"</td>"

                }


            }
        $('#insertData').append(displayItems);
        }
```

Also how should I update the table as I am using the append function at last , so it is appending the data at last, which results in duplication.How to solve this?

My data in the localStorage is like this:

```
[{"name":"s","emailId":"s@s.com","phoneNo":"9044265063","category":"astrologer"},{"name":"m","emailId":"mishra@yahoo.com","phoneNo":"8050005972","category":"astrologer"}]
```

My Full HTML data is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="displayItemsJS.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HomeStyle.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="containerDisplayItems">

<table class="ButtonDisplayItems">

<tr id="rowForButtons">

<td class="buttonsOper">
<input type="button" value="Add" id="AddButton"/> 
</td>

<td class="buttonsOper">
<input type="button" value="Delete" id="DeleteButton"/> 
</td>

</tr>
</table>
<table id="insertData"  cellspacing="3">
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My full javascript page is:

/**
 * 
 */

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var categorySelected=localStorage.getItem("category");

    $('#AddButton').attr('value','Add '+categorySelected);
    $('#DeleteButton').attr('value','Delete '+categorySelected);


    $('#AddButton').click(function(){

        $('.contentPart').load('addCategoryItem.html');
    });


    $('#DeleteButton').click(function(){

        $('input:checkbox[name='+categorySelected+']').each(function() 
                {    
                    if($(this).is(':checked'))
                        {
                        var valueOfCheckbox=$(this).val();


                        var getUserDetails=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userDetails"));

                        for(i=0;i<getUserDetails.length;i++)
                            {
                            if(getUserDetails[i].phoneNo==valueOfCheckbox)
                                {
                                getUserDetails[i].category="";
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    localStorage.setItem("userDetails", JSON.stringify(getUserDetails));
                    $('#insertData').append(displayItems);

                });

    });

    var displayItems="";
    var getItemsFromStorage=localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
    var getCategory=localStorage.getItem("category");
    if(getItemsFromStorage!=null)
        {
        var getItemsFromStorageJSON=JSON.parse(getItemsFromStorage);
        var i;
        for( i=0;i<getItemsFromStorageJSON.length;i++)
            {
            if((getItemsFromStorageJSON[i].category)==getCategory)
                {

                displayItems+="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='"+getItemsFromStorageJSON[i].category+"' value='"+getItemsFromStorageJSON[i].phoneNo+"'/></td><td>"+getItemsFromStorageJSON[i].name+"</td><td>"+getItemsFromStorageJSON[i].emailId+"</td><td>"+getItemsFromStorageJSON[i].phoneNo+"</td>"
                }

            }
        $('#insertData').append(displayItems);
        }

});
```

Comment: Where's your HTML?

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: Didn't help. All of the elements that you reference in the jQuery are not present, so I have no way of knowing if it's because of the checkboxes or the `#deleteButton` or whatever. Do you have the full HTML?

Comment: I have added the full html and js pages, the .contentPart is the div class to load a particular html. Please let me know if you don't understand now any thing in the code.

Comment: In your question you state that you want to avoid duplication. Instead of using `.append()` you can use `.html()`. I can put down an answer if this answers the question.

Comment: this .html is working but my localStorage becomes undefined after clicking on the Delete button, Suppose if I have 2 records , then on deleting one of them , my localStorage variable becomes undefined.